# What is the point of SharedPreferences.getFloat()

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

The method [`getFloat()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getFloat%28java.lang.String,%20float%29) exists to pull a float value from android's `SharedPreferences` API. Yet, in the xml, [`EditTextPreference`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/EditTextPreference.html) always stores a string value, even if numeric is defined.

One would expect `getFloat()` to automatically return this but instead it throws a `ClassCastException` and we have to use `Float.parseFloat(SharedPreferences.getString())` to get this value.

Is there literally no use for `getFloat()` or am I missing something here?

Comment: If I understand correctly then, in regards to storing edit text field values, yes you store them as strings and don't use getFloat(). From my knowledge getFloat() is used more so to store math variables or even possibly GPS coordinates.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> The method getFloat() exists to pull a float value from android's SharedPreferences API.

Yes.

> Yet, in the xml, EditTextPreference always stores a string value, even if numeric is defined.

I think you are mixing up things here. You are setting `SharedPreferences` equal to elements on a `PreferenceScreen`.

`PreferenceScreen's` save all their values into your `SharedPreferences` and it's true that `EditTextPreferences` can't save a float, but you can however save a float into your `SharedPreferences` yourself:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putFloat("aFloat", 1.2f);
editor.commit();
```

and then retrieve the float like this:

```
float someFloat = prefs.getFloat("aFloat", 0.0f);
```

Comment: Aha! So there is a use for it! Although I still wished getFloat() tried to cast the string first before complaining.

Comment: Just as a question of interest without being able to test myself right now, will it let you store 1.2 as a float or do you need to explicitly declare it as a float with 1.2f

Comment: @zgc7009 whups, yes of course it has to be 1.2f. Thanks, I corrected it.

Comment: SharedPreferences.getLong() also results in ClassCastException - I think these methods are in fact useless

Comment: @Price can you give me the exact Log? This shouldn't be.